# Symfony 5.4 migration / undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Configuration::setSchemaIgnoreClasses()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony app made from 4.3 that I want to upgrade to Symfony 5.4

I followed Symfony instructions but I am stucked with an error which seems to block the cache warm-up.

> Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
>
> !!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
> Doctrine\ORM\Configuration::setSchemaIgnoreClasses() in
> .../var/cache/prod/ContainerIt7yNV0/App_KernelProdContainer.php:1338

I tried to remove then reinstall all the doctrine bundles, but the problem is still here.
I read somewhere that this error appeared only with doctrine-bundle 2.7.0 but here I have the same with the 2.0

Would someone have an idea which could help me ?
Here is the composer.json :

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-http": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "^1.11",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/intl": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/notifier": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/process": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/string": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/translation": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/validator": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.7",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.4.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/browser-kit": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.4",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "5.4"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.4.*",
            "docker": false
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete manually var/cache/prod .
It's probably a rights issue. (write or delete /var/cache)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this many times... Even after the manual deletion, the var/cache/ is regenerated and the issue comes back.